# using clojure.string causes WARNINGs

Tags: clojure

When using clojure.string, I receive the following warnings

```
WARNING: replace already refers to: #'clojure.core/replace in namespace: tutorial.regexp, being replaced by: #'clojure.string/replace
WARNING: reverse already refers to: #'clojure.core/reverse in namespace: tutorial.regexp, being replaced by: #'clojure.string/reverse
```

my clojure script is:

```
(ns play-with-it
  (:use [clojure.string]))
```

Is there any way to fix those warnings?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, switch to

```
(ns play-with-it
  (:require [clojure.string :as string]))
```

and then say e.g.

```
(string/replace ...)
```

to call `clojure.string`'s `replace` function.

With `:use`, you bring in all Vars from `clojure.string` directly into your namespace, and since some of those have names clashing with Vars in `clojure.core`, you get the warning. Then you'd have to say `clojure.core/replace` to get at what's usually simply called `replace`.

The clash of names is by design; `clojure.string` is meant to be `require`d with an alias like this. `str` and `string` are the most frequently chosen aliases.

Comment: Thanks. Was it possible to undestand that from the doc of `use`?" Like `require`, but also refers to each lib's namespace using `clojure.core/refer`" What do they mean by this sentence?

Comment: It means that `use` does exactly what `require` does and then on top of that it asks `refer` to create mappings in the current namespace for stuff exported by the namespace being `use`d. (What I called *bring[ing] all Vars from [the `use`d namespace] directly into your namespace* above.) Cf. `(doc refer)`.

Comment: Joy of Clojure explains these pretty well too.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to Michał's answer, you can exclude vars from `clojure.core`:

```
user=> (ns foo)
nil
foo=> (defn map [])
WARNING: map already refers to: #'clojure.core/map in namespace: foo, being replaced by: #'foo/map
#'foo/map
foo=> (ns bar
        (:refer-clojure :exclude [map]))
nil
bar=> (defn map [])
#'bar/map
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Alex's answer you can also refer only the vars you want from a given namespace.

```
(ns foo.core
  (:use [clojure.string :only (replace-first)]))
```

This would not throw a warning since `replace-first` is not in `clojure.core`. However, you would still receive a warning if you did the following:

```
(ns foo.core
  (:use [clojure.string :only (replace)]))
```

In general it seems people are tending toward `(ns foo.bar (:require [foo.bar :as baz]))`.

Answer (score 1):

Since Clojure 1.4 you can refer the individual functions you need from a namespace using `:require` with a `:refer`:

```
(ns play-with-it
  (:require [clojure.string :refer [replace-first]]))
```

This is now recommended over `:use`.

Assuming you don't need the `clojure.string/replace` or `clojure.string/reverse`, that would also remove the warnings.

See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10358149/in-clojure-1-4-what-is-the-use-of-refer-within-require) and [this JIRA issue](http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-879) for more details.